# Azure Python Web App Pythonnet Installation

Tags: python, azure, mono

I am trying to Publish a flask API app to Azure Web App - Python 3.7 - Linux.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux-01

Within this App I utilize `Pythonnet` which works find in my local windows environment, but get the following error when trying to install this via pip:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'mono tools/nuget/nuget.exe update -self' returned non-zero exit status 127.

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

Is anyone able to confirm how to get pythonnet running on a Linux Python WebApp? I am deploying the app via visual Studio Code Azure App Service plugin.

Comment: well, if you are running Windows locally, have you tried a Windows App Service instead of Linux to see if that generally works?

Comment: Trying to install pythonnet in various ways has failed. If you must use linux, it is recommended to use container webapp.

Comment: Microsoft suggest stick to the Linux version as they have deprecated support for the Windows python - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service?view=vs-2019